# KDE: how to remove file association

Tags: kde-4

I'm on Kubuntu 11.04, and I have 1000 associations to wine's vlc - none of them is useful - and I want to remove them all. So I do

```
kcmshell4 filetypes
```

in konsole, then type "vlc" in a search box - it gives associations - but I can't remove associations like

```
x-wine-extension-m4p
```

for "remove" button is not available on them (and on them only). Nor

```
sudo kcmshell4 filetypes
```

helps.

So my question is: "how to remove association to vlc of 100 file types?" (you can do them one by one - but that's not the way it's supposed to be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wine keeps all those extensions this way:

```
$HOME/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-*.desktop
```

You can mark and remove all the extensions you don't want, and they will not appear in the menu anymore. Application icons may help you do it quickly.

Comment: They've really gone as associations. I still have them though as a "known types" in 'File Associations'. I've also cleaned `mimetype.list` of all wines. Great! Thanks!